# Extension of student Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, study

I'm a Hotel Management student in the Canton of Lucerne and currently doing my internship in Interlaken, Bern. My internship is about to finish in December, and my Schengen visa validity is to the 11th of January 2017. I want to extend my visa until the 25th of January 2017. Is it possible for me to get an extension of my visa?

Comment: How long have you been in Switzerland? What does your visa say? In all likelihood what you have is not a Schengen visa but a national visa, which means the rules are different. But you probably still need a reason to extend the visa, if you are not studying anymore, you could try to go for a Schengen visa or a job search visa (if such a thing even exists in Switzerland) instead of a renewal but that's not easy.